# Flutter Web - Setar parâmetros

Tags: flutter

boa tarde!! Estou desenvolvendo uma página web usando o Flutter Web. Porém essa página possui uma query string com um parâmetro, exemplo: "?recipeId=E4Rt6YU8IoD33rt". Eu preciso pegar esse parâmetro dentro do Flutter. Eu já sei como pegar, mas não sei como colocar essa query string no debug do Flutter Web. Já tentei forçar, mas sempre redireciona para http://localhost:5000/#/
O mais lógico foi eu tentar colocar antes do "#", ficando assim: http://localhost:5000/?recipeId=E4Rt6YU8IoD33rt#/, mas acaba redirecionando automaticamente para http://localhost:5000/#/. Já tentei colocar depois do '#' e depois do '#/" também, sem sucesso...

Alguém aqui já passou por isso? Tem alguma forma de manter essa query string na URL do debug?

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Utilize rotas nomeadas, pode você pode dar uma olhada nesse package [flutter_modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular#router-generic-types) para tentar ter uma ideia.

Answer (score 0):

Procure como usar ROTAS com flutter, pode lhe ajudar.

um link que pode te ajudar:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplo/aplicacao-flutter-rotas-de-navegacao/107